# Scrollbar partially hidden

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and try to create a layout with two requirements. On large devices I'd like to have only a scrollbar on a single column. However, on smaller devices I'd like to have scrollbar for the whole page.

Using `d-flex` I got my first requirement to work. However, on smaller devices the lower part of the scrollbar is partially hidden.

Heres my code: https://jsfiddle.net/vu8nma4s/

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column vh-100">
    <div class="row bg-dark">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            Top bar
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row flex-grow-1 overflow-hidden">

        <div class="col-md-2 bg-success">
            side bar
        </div>

        <div class="col-md mh-100 overflow-auto bg-info">
            <p>Main</p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. END.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row bg-warning">
        <div class="col-md">Footer</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I've put `overflow-auto` on the wrong component.

Here's my working code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col d-flex flex-column vh-100">

            <div class="row bg-dark">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    Top bar
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row flex-grow-1 overflow-auto">
                <div class="col-md-2 bg-success">
                    side bar 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-10 bg-info">
                    <p>Main</p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. END.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row bg-warning">
                <div class="col-md">Footer</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sjfzr6yv/

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .footer {
            position: absolute;

            width: 100%;
            height: 60px;
            line-height: 60px;
            background-color: #343a40;
        }

        @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
            .sideBar {
                position: sticky;
                top: 40px;
                width: 16vw;
            }

        }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                   aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2 ">
            <div class="sideBar">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">Bras justo odio</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">111111111</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">222222222</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">3333333333</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">444444444</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">555555555</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
            <div class="mainContent">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                    et
                    dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                    aliquip
                    ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
                    dolore eu
                    fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
                    deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
                    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
                    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                    reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
                    occaecat
                    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum
                    dolor
                    sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
                    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                    commodo
                    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
                    nulla
                    pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
                    anim
                    id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                    ullamco
                    laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
                    velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
                    sunt
                    in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                    adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
                    veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                    irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
                    Excepteur
                    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    END.


                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                    et
                    dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                    aliquip
                    ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
                    dolore eu
                    fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
                    deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
                    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
                    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                    reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
                    occaecat
                    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum
                    dolor
                    sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
                    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                    commodo
                    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
                    nulla
                    pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
                    anim
                    id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                    ullamco
                    laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
                    velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
                    sunt
                    in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                    adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
                    veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                    irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
                    Excepteur
                    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    END.


                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                    et
                    dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                    aliquip
                    ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
                    dolore eu
                    fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
                    deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
                    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
                    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                    reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
                    occaecat
                    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum
                    dolor
                    sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
                    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                    commodo
                    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
                    nulla
                    pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
                    anim
                    id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                    ullamco
                    laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
                    velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
                    sunt
                    in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                    adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
                    veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                    irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
                    Excepteur
                    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    END. sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
                    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                    commodo
                    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
                    nulla
                    pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
                    anim
                    id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                    ullamco
                    laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
                    velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
                    sunt
                    in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                    adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
                    veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                    irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
                    Excepteur
                    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    END.


                </p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Do you know any Bootstrap only variant? Can you elaborate on where the 900px min-width comes from?

Comment: I determined that the sidebar should be fixed when the screen size is more than 900px. I mean for larger devices.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still doesn't work. At least in Chrome and Edge the scrollbar is still hidden behind the footer.

Comment: OK, I'ii check it again. another question; Do you want the sidebar to be fixed on large devices?